# Magento 2.15 override PackagesData.php in setup

Tags: magento2, overrides, magento2.1.5

How can I override the class `PackagesData.php` in namespace `Magento\Setup\Model`?

I created the file `app/code/local/Magento/Setup/Model/PackagesData.php` but this is not working.

Comment: Try this with composer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140088/magento2-applying-patches/140090#140090